# unexpected tokenize xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, tokenize

I have a series of files, some of which I need to tokenize, some of which not.

this is an example of both types

```
file 1
<div>
text 〈: in latere intuentibus sinistro〉 text 〈: in latere intuentibus dextro〉 text
</div>

file 2
<div>
text 〈: in latere intuentibus sinistro〉 text 
</div>

file 3
<div>
text 
</div>
```

the code I have done in my understanding should first look for the separating string 〈:***whichever***〉, but only use it to tokenize when it is there. if that is not present, just apply other templates.

```
    <xsl:variable name="sections">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(〈):(in latere intuentibus sinistro|in latere intuentibus dextro|in epystilio|in ipsa aedicula|in una linea|in parte aversa|in fgr.\s\w*\s*|in columna\s\w*\s*)(〉)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:sequence select="."/> 
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template name="div">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <head>Text</head>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(., $sections)">
                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., $sections)">
                        <div n="{position()}" type="textpart">
                            <ab>
                             ...
                            </ab>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <ab>
                        ...
                    </ab>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
```

What happens is that with example 1 it returns the string, in example 2 actually performs the tokenize() and do the rest of the work nicely, in example 3 I get an Error (rightly) saying that tokenize is a zero length string... I understand why this second error comes, as the string is not there. I do not understand why it got to the point of evaluating that piece of xsl.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When processing your file 3, you initialize the variable $sections to the part of the string that matches your regular expression.  Nothing in the input matches the regular expression, and you have no xsl:non-matching-substring element, so the value of the xsl:analyze-string instruction, and thus of the variable $sections, is the empty sequence.

In the template for 'div', you test the condition `contains(., $sections)`.  When either argument to the `contains` function is the empty sequence, it is treated as if it were the empty string.  So the test is now effectively `contains(.,'')`, which evaluates to true.  That is why the stylesheet gets to the point of evaluating that piece of XSLT.

You don't ask why the first file is not matching; I suspect but have not verified that it's because the value of $sections is a sequence of two strings, instead of a single string (but in that case I'm puzzled that you don't report an error when it's used as the second argument of `contains()`).  [Wrong.  But see Michael Kay's comment below, which corrects my error.]

You may get results that are more nearly what you expect if you use the `matches` function instead of `contains` in your test, and tokenize using your regular expression rather than using the matching literal string.

The errors might prove easier to diagnose if you use `as="xsd:string"` in the declaration of $sections, to tell the process what kind of value you expect $sections to take -- the processor would then have told you in file 1 that you were assigning a sequence of strings, not one, to it, and in file 3 that you were assigning the empty sequence to is.  This is academic if you take my advice not to bother with the $sections variable, but it remains true:  adding `as` attributes has caught more bugs for me, at lower cost in time and frustration, than any other property of XSLT 2.0 except the fact that the syntax is XML.

Comment: In fact, in the absence of an "as" attribute, $sections is a document node; the two strings returned by xsl:sequence therefore get concatenated into the content of this document, and the contains() call uses the string value of the document node, which is the concatenated value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have used matches and now it works + I hope I have learned something for next time!